# Java Google App Engine: Do I need to make an object persistent before adding it to another persistent object's persistent data structure?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Let's say I have a class `Employee` and a class `Company` which holds a LinkedList of `Employee` objects, and I want to write a method that adds an `Employee` to the database in a specific `Company`. I create a new `Company` object and add it to the database with the new `Employee` if the `Company` does not already exit. Else, I add the new `Employee` to the specified `Company`'s `LinkedList<Employee> employee`.

My question is, do I need to make the new Employee persistent before adding it to the LinkedList, which is in itself persistent? Or can I just say something like:

```
 public void addEmployeeToCompany(Employee employee, companyName) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        Company company = pm.getObjectById(Company.class.getSimpleName(), companyName);
        if(company != null) { 
            company.addEmployee(employee);
        }
        else { 
            Company newCompany = new Company(companyName, employee);
            Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Company.class.getSimpleName(), companyName);
            newCompany.setKey(key);
        pm.makePersistent(newCompany);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, persisting only company should persist employees as well. But the real question is what annotations do your company and employee classes have? Also, do you have any specific problem with this, that is, why are you asking - are you getting an exception?

Comment: Both Employee and Company are marked @PersistenceCapable. 
I'm not having any specific problems. I am in the midst of learning about databases and was just wondering. 

Thank you!

Comment: I think all I am missing is pm.makePersistent(venue) after company.addEmployee(employee).